# Выбор базы данных для одного файла XML

Tags: mysql, база-данных, node.js, xml, angular

Недавно впервые столкнулся в web разработкой.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы у пользователя был личный кабинет. В нём около 27 - 30 полей для заполнения. Данные этих полей должны хранится и загружаться в **одном** XML файле (это жёсткое условие).

Посоветуйте легковесную базу данных для работы с одним XML файлом на стороне сервера. На данный момент я склоняюсь к MySQL.

Разработка ведётся с использованием Angular, NodeJS. В XML файле порядка 2500 записей по 30 полей.

P.S. Речь идёт о персональных данных пользователей, поэтому вопрос безопасности открыт.

Comment: *для работы с одним XML файлом на стороне сервера* Для КАКОЙ работы? Хранить - это ни разу не работа... Ну и чтобы два раза не бегать - почему именно XML? Чем определяется - даже не столько выбор, сколько жёсткий отказ от иных форматов.

Comment: @Akina, Под работой подразумевается то, что:
1) На сервер выгружается один файл в формате XML. Это зависит не от меня.
2) Для конкретного пользователя с этого файла берутся значения для заполнения странички личного кабинета.
3) Пользователь редактирует данные
4) В соответствии с введённой информацией в этот ОДИН XML файл вносятся изменения.
Формат выгрузки жёстко определён не мною, поэтому нельзя использовать тот же JSON

Comment: Нет, просто мне странен вот какой момент - ладно, кем-то формат определён... но получаете его для записи в БД именно Вы! и вычитывать оттуда будете опять же Вы! И я не понимаю, что Вас заставляет НЕ ПРЕОБРАЗОВЫВАТЬ этот файл - всё равно ВАШ код записывает и ВАШ код получает. Кто бы и что жёстко не установил - но он в БД своим кодом не полезет, он обратится к Вашей процедуре или методу. И что там у Вашего интерфейса под капотом - XML, JSON или порублено на поля, MySQL, SQLite или Plain text, - он и не посмотрит, и не узнает, ибо неинтересно ему... верно?

Comment: Ну да пофиг... просто проблема в том, что реально лёгкие СУБД не рвутся реализовывать XML data type - так что Вам придётся тело файла класть в поле с самым обычным типом TEXT. Что уже само по себе есть конвертация формата.

Comment: @Akina, наверно я неправильно сформулировал вопрос. У меня на входе есть этот 1 XML и на выходе 1 XML. Всё что происходит между этими стадиями - неважно. Например, я могу посимвольно в двоичном коде читать и записывать символы (отвратительный пример). Вопрос в другом.  Что лучше использовать для хранения 2500 строк по 30 полей (крайне маленькая БД получается). Какую легковесную БД выбрать?? Ведь ради такого объёма данных нет смысла разворачивать, например, MSSQL Server17. Должны же быть более изящные решения

Comment: *2500 строк по 30 полей* А в килограммах-то это сколько? а то, знаете ли, и простого текстового файла хватит. Можно один на всех, можно по одному на юзера. Прочитал и распарсил, получил и записал... И что тут делать СУБД - не понимаю. Ну а если "Речь идёт о персональных данных пользователей, поэтому вопрос безопасности открыт" - то перед записью шифруем, после чтения расшифровываем по сертификату, тоже процедура стандартная.

Comment: Приходят данные => парсишь xml в js => сохраняешь в js.
Приходит запрос на данный сервер => получаешь данные из бд => парсишь js в xml => отправляешь на сервер

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, правильным решением вашей задачи будет использование классической реляционной базы данных (MySQL, Postgres) и отдельный интерфейс для экспортированная данных в XML формат.